# Mass remove lines that contain certain words?

Tags: command-line, command

I need to remove any lines that contain certain keywords in them from a huge list of text files I have in a directory.

For example, I need all lines with **any** of these keywords in them to be removed:  test1, example4, coding9

This is the closest example to what I'm trying to do that I can find:

```
sed '/Unix\|Linux/d' *.txt
```

Note:  the lines don't need to contain all the keywords to be removed, just one should remove it :)

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: On the command line?  I can write a very simple Perl script that would do the trick.  :-/

Comment: Perl sounds good to me, the only way I've found to do it is with Notepad++ by bookmarking all the lines but since this covers millions of lines across thousands of files, that's just taking too long to do.

Comment: This actually looks like it works almost perfect:  `sed '/test1\|whois\|test2\|test3\|test4\|test5/d' *.txt` but it just outputs all the lines in terminal.  What would need to be changed for the files to actually be edited to have those lines removed?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking for some 1 liner command to read and write back to thousands of files and millions of lines.  I wouldn't do it like that personally because I would prefer to write a quick and dirty script in Perl.  I very briefly tested this on very simple files and it works but since you are working with thousands of files and millions of lines, I would test whatever you write in a test directory first with some of the files so that you can verify.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# the initial directory to read from
my $directory = 'tmp';
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;

my @keywords = ('woohoo', 'blah');

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    # ignore files that begin with a period
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);

    # open the file
    open F, $directory.'/'.$file || die $!;
    # initialize empty file_lines
    @file_lines = ();

    # role through and push the line into the new array if no keywords are found
    while (<F>) {
        next if checkForKeyword($_);
        push @file_lines, $_;
    }
    close F;

    # save in a temporary file for testing
    # just change these 2 variables to fit your needs
    $save_directory = $directory.'-save';
    $save_file = $file.'-tmp.txt';
    if (! -d $save_directory) {
        `mkdir $save_directory`;
    }
    $new_file = $save_directory.'/'.$save_file;
    open S, ">$new_file" || die $!;
    print S for @file_lines;
    close S;
}

# role through each keyword and return 1 if found, return '' if not
sub checkForKeyword()
{
     $line = shift;
     for (0 .. $#keywords) {
         $k = $keywords[$_];
         if ($line =~ m/$k/) {
           return 1;
         }
     }
     return '';
}
```